# Uncaught exception 'Zend_View_Exception'

Tags: zend-framework, zend-studio

For my project I have added following line of code in **applicaiton.ini**

**resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"**

Whenever I add this code, am getting following error,

**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_View_Exception' with message 'script 'layout.phtml' not found in path

Bellow is the structure of my project

** [image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Folder for the layout must be located in "application".

```
/application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml
```

Comment: Thanks, it got fixed. I have one more Q, does DbTable should be under applicaiton folder, bec am getting this error  Fatal error: Class 'Application_Model_DbTable_Albums' not found

Comment: I would move the folder to /applicatio/models